# How do I open multiple files in vim as one contiguous file?

Tags: vim, macvim

My workflow is currently to have multiple classes in one file. I'm about to switch to having each class in an individual file, but they're inter-related. I find it frustrating to switch tabs and then jump to the line I'm looking for, similarly jumping windows and then jumping to lines seems like a waste of time. I'd like to open multiple files as though they were a single concatenated file so that I can maintain my current editing flow with a more clear file hierarchy. Essentially, holding down j would move me through multiple files seamlessly and moving through search results would carry through multiple files as well. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Vim isn't really built for working on a group (project) of files...
That is why people switched to using IDE type tools where you can group multiple files/classes/resources together and switch between them not only by selecting each file using a solution/project list but also usually using additionally higher level language specific constructs like right click to move to the file/line where this function/variable is defined or used for example...

Comment: Maybe there is a fuse fs that supports that (or maybe you can write one). Otherwise, I'm sceptical.

Comment: What language are you using on your mac? Maybe I or someone else can recommend a good IDE for it?

Comment: If you really like editing using Vim Some IDE's let you still use VIM style editing using a plug-in.

Comment: I'm using Vim for Javascript. I find IDEs for Javascript to not be worth the hassle. IDEs tend to solve this problem the same way Vim works with tabs and hierarchies but I still need to switch between the files in some way.

Comment: @Redian consider looking at ctags which allows you to jump to function definitions. Or something like ctrl-p which allows you to find files/buffers quickly

Comment: This might help you search across all open buffers: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Run_a_command_in_multiple_buffers

Comment: This seems like something you should handle with splits. The files won't be opened in a single pane but you'll be able to see them all at once.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to change your workflow slightly. Rather than opening multiple files as one contiguous file, make use of features designed for navigation and searching.

**Holding Down j**

Rather than holding down `j` for a long time, consider:

- `{`, `}` - jump up/down paragraph
- `]m`, `[m`, `]M`, `[M` - jump up/down to next method start/end
- `]]`, `[[`, `][`, `[]` - jump up/down to next class start/end
- `ctrl-f`, `ctrl-b`, `ctrl-u`, `ctrl-d` - page up/down, half-page up/down
- `H`, `M`, `L` - move cursor to top, middle, or bottom of screen
- more from vim help: `:help various-motions`

**Searching through multiple files**

My workflow usually doesn't involve search-navigating through multiple files, but you can `:vimgrep` (and navigate to next, prev, with `:cn`, `:cp`). There's a whole wiki about different ways to search: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Find_in_files_within_Vim

As mentioned in comments, `ctags` is also a solution for multi-file navigation in order to jump to class or method name definitions:

- `ctrl-]` - go to definition
- `<ctrl-w>]`, `<ctrl-w>}` - open def in split/preview-window (`<ctrl-w>T` to open split to new tab)

**On handling multiple files:**

While @AnthonyLambert's comment about vanilla vim's multi-file handling is semi-true, there are many plugins that completely alleviate this problem for me. I personally make use of NERDTree + NERDTreeTabs to create an IDE-like project browser, CtrlP for fuzzy-filename matching, and also just basic vim windows, tabs, and buffers.